# Как отобразить массив в удобочитаемом виде?

Tags: php, sql, массивы, phpmyadmin

Нашел в таблице в phpmyadmin такой массив данных:

```
a:607:{s:8:"last_tab";s:1:"1";s:15:"homey_site_mode";s:7:"per_day";s:21:"homey_calendar_months";s:2:"12";s:17:"homey_date_format";s:8:"dd-mm-yy";s:17:"homey_time_format";s:2:"24";s:18:"users_admin_access";s:1:"1";s:17:"hide-host-contact";s:1:"0";s:11:"menu-sticky";s:1:"0";s:13:"sticky_search";s:1:"0";s:15:"site_breadcrumb";s:1:"1";s:14:"sticky_sidebar";a:4:{s:15:"default_sidebar";s:1:"1";s:15:"listing_sidebar";s:1:"1";s:12:"page_sidebar";s:0:"";s:12:"blog_sidebar";s:0:"";}s:19:"glc_day_night_label";s:8:"ночь";s:20:"glc_day_nights_label";s:10:"ночей";s:14:"glc_hour_label";s:6:"час";s:15:"glc_hours_label";s:10:"часов";s:15:"cmn_guest_label";s:10:"гость";s:16:"cmn_guests_label";s:12:"гостей";s:13:"srh_whr_to_go";s:22:"Куда пойдем?";
```

Подскажите, если онлайн генераторы которые смогут его отобразить в понятном виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php вы можете воспользоваться функцией `unserialize()`

Вот тут подробнее:
[serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php), [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже подобный вопрос, нашёл вот такое в интернете: [инструмент unserialize](https://www.unserialize.com/s/024b7520-d779-32c9-cb75-00005cf4cebb)

Answer (score 0):

```
$stats_order = '<сериализованные данные>';
$test = unserialize($stats_order_res);
echo '<pre>', print_r( $test ), '</pre>';
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]